# how to display the table, after a specific codition?

Tags: php, mysql

I have coded as such, on uploading an excel file, the list of data in excel will be displayed in table.

Now the problem is on deleting the data, the below particular row is alone displayed.

```
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox"  name="delete_all" class="" value='' onClick="deleteAll()"  /></th>
</tr>
```

I want the entire table to be shown only when there is more that one row. Please help me with this.

```
<form name="del_functionality" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];     ?>">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls" align="right">        
            <button type="submit" id="deletes" name="delete" value="delete"  data-loading-text="Loading..." onClick="return deleteSelected()">Delete </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox"  name="delete_all" class="" value='' onClick="deleteAll()"  /></th>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer_tbl");
        while($dealer_row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['firstname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['phone']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href='dealer_edit.php?did=<?=$dealer_row['uid']?>'>Edit</a> </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox_del[]" class="deleteCheckbox" value="<?php echo $dealer_row['uid']; ?>"  />
                    <input type='hidden' name='deleteConfirm' value='0' />
                </td> 
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is obsolete. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. You should use PDO or mysqli_

Answer (score 0):

Change query position like below:

```
<?php 
      $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer_tbl");
      $count =mysql_num_rows($res);
 ?>
 <table class="table" <?php if($count == 0) { ?> style="display:none;" <?php }?>>
 ...
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. you can get the no  of rows from your query outside the `form` and if that is `greater than 0` you can show the result.

```
<?php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer_tbl");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($num_rows>0)
{
?>
<form name="del_functionality" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];     ?>">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls" align="right">        
            <button type="submit" id="deletes" name="delete" value="delete"  data-loading-text="Loading..." onClick="return deleteSelected()">Delete </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox"  name="delete_all" class="" value='' onClick="deleteAll()"  /></th>
        </tr>
    <?php

        while($dealer_row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['firstname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dealer_row['phone']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href='dealer_edit.php?did=<?=$dealer_row['uid']?>'>Edit</a> </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox_del[]" class="deleteCheckbox" value="<?php echo $dealer_row['uid']; ?>"  />
                    <input type='hidden' name='deleteConfirm' value='0' />
                </td> 
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</form>  
<?php
}
else
{
        echo "No result Found !! ";
}
?>
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated now so please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`